# Как сделать три колонки на css

Tags: css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как при помощи css сделать три горизонтальных колонки ?

Две я сделал, а вот с центральной ни как разобраться не могу.

```
#column-1 {
border: 1px solid #DDD;
padding: 10px 10px;
width: 48.6%;
float: left;
}
#column-2 {

}
#column-3 {
border: 1px solid #DDD;
padding: 10px 10px;
width: 48.6%;
float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вот Вам пример резинового макета - http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/5rpJN/6/**

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#column-1 {
  width: 20%;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#column-2 {
  background: green;
  width: 60%;
  min-height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#column-3 {
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="column-1">left</div>
<div id="column-2">center</div>
<div id="column-3">right</div>
```

*Спрашивайте, если вдруг не понятно...*

**А вот Вам еще в догонку фиксированный макет - http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/4UtDc/4/**

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
}

#column-1,
#column-2,
#column-3 {
  float: left;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#column-1 {
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}

#column-2 {
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
}

#column-3 {
  width: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="column-1">left</div>
  <div id="column-2">center</div>
  <div id="column-3">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, кстати, не забывайте учитывать, что если вы будете задавать такие свойства как padding и border, то и размер блоков, для которых эти правила были заданы, будет увеличен.
если нужно, чтобы размер не менялся, то учитывайте это в коде.
например, нам нужно чтобы блок был шириной и высотой в 100px;
напишем такой код:

    div {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 10px;
    }

Ширина и высота блока в данном случае = 140px;

Для того, чтобы этого избежать, уменьшаем размер блока на 40px; или используем свойство css3 box-sizing: border-box;

Удачи

Answer (score -1):

Примерно так должно

```
<div class="content row">
    <div class="column">Горизонтальная калонка1</div>
    <div class="column">Горизонтальная калонка2</div>
    <div class="column">Горизонтальная калонка3</div>
</div>
css:
    .column{border: 1px solid #DDD;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    height:400x; //например
    }
.row:after{
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}
```